# Login Form in Angular2 using ngSubmit

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a login form where I want to validate the email id and password. I have tried passing the id and password to the typescript file. But only the email id is being passed not the password. Here's the HTML code.

```html
<form #instituteForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="instituteLogin(instituteForm)">
        <div id="user-data">
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Facility ID</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="facilityId" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="institute.facilityId">
            <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!email.valid && email.touched">Please enter a valid email!</span>
            <label for="password">Passkey</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="facilityPasskey" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="institute.facilityPasskey">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
     
      </form>
```

```js
 institute = {
    facilityId: '',
    facilityPasskey: ''
  };
  submitted = false;

  instituteLogin(instForm: NgForm){
    console.log("Going from facility to login");
    //DONE:   instForm.value['facilityID']
    // instForm.value['facilityPasskry']
    console.log(instForm.value);
   
    {this.router.navigateByUrl('/login/olduser');}
  }
```

[Output on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhoNK.jpg)

Comment: Try `instForm.value['facilityPasskey']`; you've misspelled the word.

Comment: // instForm.value['facilityPasskry'] I think you have misspelled the faciityPasskey.

Comment: Is `facilityPasskey` misspelled or it's just in the code snippet that it is misspelled?

Comment: @NicholasK , the misspelled word commented out. That wasn't causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this StackBlitz. [StackBlitz Link of problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rcds9k)

Answer (score 1):

There is validation error, You forgot to add  `#facilityId="ngModel"` in input and change validation by

```
 <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!facilityId.valid &&
 facilityId.touched">Please enter a valid email!</span>
```

so after changes you can get both value, check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-ngsubmit-bbvgpi?file=app/app.component.html)